# Why would a Calendar Id change when using the Outlook REST API?

Tags: outlook-restapi

We have an application built that uses both the V1 and V2 versions of the Outlook REST API.  We occasionally witness the calendar id for a user's calendar change.

Specifically... 
we fetch calendars using the GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars API call.  We store the Id property for each calendar.

Later (normally weeks or months later) if we make the same call using the same Oauth2 token, we get back a different Id for each calendar.

The same thing happens with the both the V1 and V2 versions of the above endpoint.

This doesn't happen all the time... it happens only for some calendars... and only for some calendars within one O365 account.  We haven't been able to determine what triggers the change.

I know this is vague, but I'm wondering if anyone else has witnessed this, or might know what would cause the Id of a calendar to change.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been having the same problem, my initial guess is just that an edit was made to the calendar or something. If I manage to reproduce it I'll update here

Comment: hey y'all — were you able to find why this is happening?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found out why it happens?